# Ember -retrieving data from server to a view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, controller, view

Does anyone happen to know How to show data from server, right now ive been showing related models in basic handlebars like this

```
{{
           view Ember.Select
           prompt="Organization"
           contentBinding="organizations"
           optionValuePath="content.id"
           optionLabelPath="content.name"
           selectionBinding="selectedOrganization"
}}
```

But i need to create an has many form... which im duplicating using views? **Is using views even the right path to go** ?!

```
 {{#each view.anotherField}}
              {{view Ember.TextField value=view.name}}
 {{/each}}
```

[image]

Here is the output of my form, u can see Organizatons form being doubled
**JSbin http://jsbin.com/efeReDer/7/edit**

Today  I came up with this... :D Kinda serves the purpose ? looks ugly tho
**http://emberjs.jsbin.com/acUCocu/6/edit**

Basically i made an empty model which i then each loop.
On action i "store.create".empty record to it.
Give me your thoughts on this :)
Also is there a way to make these fields indepedent ? without all changing their content while an input is changed.
Cheers,

kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an example to work on, of what i think you are asking

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iPeHuNA/1/edit

**js**

*Tried to separate the entities related to the model of the app, from how they will be displayed.Created an ember class `App.Person` that will hold the data from server. I have not used ember-data, but it is quite easy to replace the classes with ember-data notation and the dummy ajax calls with respective store calls etc, if desired.*

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("persons");
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo("persons");
  }
});

App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    return $.ajax({url:"/"}).then(function(){/*in url it is required to place the actual server address that will return data e.g. from a rest web service*/
      /*let's imagine that the following data has been returned from the server*/
      /*i.e. two Person entities have already been stored to the server and now are retrieved to display*/

      var personsData = [];
      var person1 = App.Person.create({id:1,fname:"Person1",lname:"First",genderId:2});
      var person2 = App.Person.create({id:2,fname:"Person2",lname:"Second",genderId:1});
      personsData.pushObject(person1);
      personsData.pushObject(person2);

      return personsData;
    });
  },
  setupController:function(controller,model){


   /*this could also be retrieved from server*/
    /*let's mimic a call*/
    $.ajax({url:"/",success:function(){

      /*This will run async but ember's binding will preper everything.If this is not acceptable, then initialization of lists' values/dictionary values can take place in any earlier phase of the app.  */

      var gendersData = [];
      gendersData.pushObject(App.Gender.create({id:1,type:"male"}));
    gendersData.pushObject(App.Gender.create({id:2,type:"female"}));

    controller.set("genders",gendersData);

    model.forEach(function(person){

      person.set("gender",gendersData.findBy("id",person.get("genderId")));


    });
    }});

    controller.set("model",model);
  }
});

App.PersonsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  genders:[],
  actions:{
    addPerson:function(){
      this.get("model").pushObject(App.Person.create({id:Date.now(),fname:"",lname:""}));
    },
    print:function(){
      console.log(this.get("model"));
    }
  }
});

App.PersonFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"personForm",
  /*layoutName:"simple-row"*/
  layoutName:"collapsible-row"
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  id:null,                                
  fname:"",
  lname:"",
  gender:null
});

App.Gender = Ember.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  type:null
});
```

**html/hbs**

*created a view that takes care of how each `App.Person` instance gets rendered. As example `partial` and `layouts` have been used to accomodate bootstrap styling, as i noticed you used some in your example.*

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="persons">
        {{#each person in this}}

        {{view App.PersonFormView}}

        {{/each}}
        <br/><br/>
        {{partial "buttons"}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "addPerson"}}>
      add
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "print"}}>
      print results to console
    </button>

      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="personForm">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        {{input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value=person.fname}}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-5">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        {{input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value=person.lname}}
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">
      {{
               view Ember.Select
               prompt="Gender"
               content=controller.genders
               optionValuePath="content.id"
               optionLabelPath="content.type"
               selectionBinding=person.gender
               class="form-control"
            }}
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--</div>-->

      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="simple-row">
      <div class="row">
      {{yield}}
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="collapsible-row">
        <div class="panel-group" >
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href=#{{unbound person.id}}>
              person:{{person.fname}}
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id={{unbound person.id}} class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{yield}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </br>
      </script>

      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.1.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.2.0/ember.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: wow mate, this looks just wonderful, can't wait to dig in this =)

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iPeHuNA/7/edit  Edited this a little bit for my own workproject . I did find somethings u did there pretty hard :)

Comment: @kristjan reinhold great , nice job

Comment: I still ran into some problems, i also made my comments on this jsbin so u could understand exactly whats my form like  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/acUCocu/16 Let me know if it loads :D Had some problems with loading before = P

Comment: Your example gives me back array of inserted input data. Mine doesn't : /

Comment: @kristjanreinhold i'm not sure at which point you refer. The example i provided does not use ember-data, it takes care of the mappings and communication with the server through ajax. This is completely valid, but a bit cumborsome sometimes, depending on the structure of the system followed etc. So, ember-data simplifies this process, especially with trivial tasks. If you use ember-data be prepared to have different structures than the ones presented in my example. In addition all communication with the server will take place via store->adapter->serializer.

Comment: When i insert data with your example i get returned a data array, in my own ember data sample i dont get returned the array(simply returns an array with length 1, yours goes a,a,a,a which contains fname, lname, genderish) and i cant figure out why since we both have action "addPerson" which then adds " " to all fields, how is that possible that yours returns the true input values, thats exactly what i need, in order to later save those fields into DB =(

Comment: @kristjanreinhold when  calling `addPerson` in my example i push an empty ember object to the `model` which is an array (`ArrayController`). If you decide to use this implementation then on your `submit/save person` action you would make an ajax call and send to server the data. If you want to use ember-data, then you will manage your data through the store, of course you can also set the data as model to your controller i.e. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iPeHuNA/12 . When you decide to `save/submit` you will have to call `save` on your store.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold take a look at the guide for ember-data http://emberjs.com/guides/models/ also look at the API http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html as you will need to replace the `FixtureAdapter` with `RestAdapter`. Then by calling `save()` on `model` or each `record` the data will be sent to the server via ember-data.

Comment: http://www.upload.ee/image/3810313/ffffff.PNG I thought my array was empty, but it actually is slightly different

Comment: @kristjanreinhold you get this from store, because by calling `find` you get a promise. If you want access to your data you need to work when the promise is evaluated i.e. look at the console when calling print http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aCeFuve/1/edit , `console.log(this.store.findAll('person').then(function(a){console.log(a);}));` . You may wonder why wait for a promise to evaluate when the data is already there i just added it, well that's how ember-data works through promises.

Comment: Hello again. Im in need for some professional help again :) I made validation for my formset as well http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iDeQABo/17/edit . Do u have any idea how to merge those 2 ? Validation goes by each input value which i can request on special fields like field.newFname . Been meesing around for quite a while . Now im starting to think this form duplication maybe aint the right way, but what is? :(